# Glass Mapper IEnumerable<Guid> to IEnumerable<Object>

Tags: c#, sitecore, code-generation, glass-mapper, tds

I am using glass mapper and TDS code generation templates to generate models for my sitecore templates.

All working Good. But, If i have a multi-list field TDS templates are creating `IEnumerable<Guid>`. I want it to be `IEnumerable<OtherSitecoreTemplate>`. Its working if i manually change it. But next time when code is regenerated, all my changes will be lost.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set a custom type on your multi-list field that will be used during code generation by setting the "Custom Data" property of the field in TDS:

[image: Custom Data].

In your case, if you set this to "generic=Namespace.OtherSitecoreTemplate" the stock code generation templates for TDS will generate as `IEnumerable<OtherSitecoreTemplate>`

As an aside, this is where you'd set the type for Link fields. If you use the string "type=OtherSitecoreTemplate" it will strongly type the field to the value provided.

Comment: Looks like it does not had any effect.. still it is converting to <Guid>? is that the Sitecore template name/Id or Generated Class Name/Interface Name?

Comment: You need to set this on the field in TDS. It should be the full name (including namespace) of the class that gets generated for your other template.

Comment: Its changing it for the base_template but not for templates that are inherited form base_template. example: its changing on Footer template but not other templates which inherited from Footer template?

Comment: If you removed the template from TDS, it also probably wiped out your custom data field.